# Finding index inside a Javascript regular expression match

Tags: javascript, regex

i had string like this in javascript

```
var str = "This is my test string is Ingrédients";
```

the substring `"Ingrédients"` can be also as `"Ingredients"`
how to get the index of substring `"Ingrédients"` from the above string
by applying regular expression ( `Ingr[ée]dients` )

Answer (score 30):

If you just want to find the first occurrence of a regex match in a string, you can use `search`. If you want to find all occurrences, then you can use repeated `exec` and query the match `index` values.

Here's an example: ([see it on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/W4p0u)):

```
text = "I'm cooking; these are my Ingredients! I mean Ingrédients, yes!";
//      0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123

re = /Ingr[ée]dients/g;

print(text.search(re)); // "26"
print(text.search(re)); // "26" again

while (m = re.exec(text)) {
   print(m.index);
} // "26", "46"
```

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Javascript](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)
- [MDN - `search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) and [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Comment: Great thanks--I don't suppose there is a built in way to just get an array of all hits back (which include index information)?

Comment: There sure is chaiguy: simply iterate a while loop and push the results onto an array. It can go on one line if you like.

Answer (score -2):

Use search:

```
alert(str.search(/Ingr[ée]dients/));
```